# JQuery AJAX POST Not Working on IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, iis

Thanks in advance for any help..

I have a web service in a visual studio project that looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/Grade")]
    string gradeProcess(string s0, string s1, string s2, string s3);
```

I have another simple VS project with a simple HTML page that calls that web service like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://MyRemoteWebServer/gradeProcess.svc/Grade',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        OnSuccess(data, response);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        OnError(data, response);
    }
});
```

Locally, I can run the Web Service first (F5), and then change the url of the post in my HTML page VS project to use the local web service, run it as well, and it works perfectly fine (i.e. url: 'http://localhost/gradeProcess.svc/Grade').

Thinking I'm nearly done, I then created 2 websites on a Windows 2012 machine and published both sites to IIS 8 (changing the url of the AJAX post to reference the remote server). I can browse to both and I can see the standard ASP web service base page, as well as the HTML page. Both seem to be hosted properly.

But my POST no longer functions on this IIS server. I have tried modifying my web.config countless ways to remove WebDAVModule, settings that enable CORS, and tons of others. Tinkered with things like

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

I have modified the IIS server to make sure the SVC handlers are in place, reordered them, and again, a lot of other settings.

In Fiddler, I keep getting a "Method Not allowed" response. If I try to navigate to 'http://MyRemoteWebServer/gradeProcess.svc/Grade' with a browser, I also see the "method not allowed" warning. I guess my biggest challenge is understanding what I need to do to debug this. A part of me thinks the application/json setting is a problem, and another thinks it may be a path issue (i.e. the url path and route definition).

Any insight as to how to debug this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Post an example of 'postData' you are trying to POST.

Comment: Thanks for looking. Here is an example, before Stringify, The actual parameters in a variable (so, s1) could be large (up to 100 sets):

s0: "89.3%2039.12%2C44.77%2015.91"
s1: "49.3%2039.12%2C44.77%2015.91"
s2: ""
s3: ""
s4: ""
s5: ""
s6: ""
s7: ""
s8: ""
s9: ""

Comment: Your webmethod is accepting only 4 parameters s0, s1, s2, s3 and you are passing s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9?